# Full Frame Vs Crop Frame

Tags: full-frame

I have somewhat idea of the difference between these but would like to understand it with an example.

Few questions

Nikon D7000 Vs equivalent Full frame camera

1) **Portraits** : Would there be any difference if rest of the kit is same, like external flash, strobes etc? Would I be able to produce
equally good results professionally.

2) **Low Light Photography** : Is low light photography where the real power of full-frame professional cameras come into play?

3) **Landscapes** etc : Is full-frame required more for landscape, long distance,  Gigs etc

4) Can I use D7000 for professional **wedding photography**. If not then where does it lack.

Where is the real potential of full-frame come along. I think what I am trying to understand is what I can & can't do(By way of example)
 with crop frames professionally.

Many Thanks

Comment: At the moment, your question is pretty general and as such has been answered many times on this site already. If there's a specific point you think hasn't been dealt with, please revise your question.

Comment: Hi Philip, I agree now that I have explored more. I think the answer i was looking at is whether I can use Nikon d7000(or equivalent) for professional purposes. And what i have gathered so far from related topics is "Yes you can use it but their are pros/cons". New to this site and did not know that a redundant question can affect reputation scores :) oops....

Comment: voted to close (dupe) but also upvoted, I don't see the need for the -1, closing is sufficient in my opinion, especially for a well formatted question. And welcome to photo.stackexchange!

Comment: Thanks Paul, How do I close this now?

Comment: no worries, we'll close it out.

Comment: I've reverted the edit -- there's no point in having a post which says "don't look at this post". :) Closed questions won't normally show up but may be found in search results, and that may help some future visitor (stack exchange is smart about redirecting searchers to the earlier question in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nikon D7000 is used by many working professional wedding photographers. It isn't at the top of it's class, especially considering its age now - but that doesn't mean it isn't being used still.

*Can I use camera XYZ for professional purposes?* is only something that you can answer. If clients see your portfolio of work, and pay you to shoot their event - then **whatever tools you use to achieve success is up to you**. No "photography police" are going to tell you that a D7000 *isn't enough* or that it *isn't professional*. I've seen people who charge money for photography and are using a Nikon D3200 with a kit lens. Is that a good idea; no not really - but again no one is going to stop you.

As already noted, the previous answer comparing crop sensor(APS-C) camera such as the D7000 to full frame(FX) cameras such as the D610 explains many of your questions well:

- [When do the differences between APS-C and full frame sensors matter, and why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-do-the-differences-between-aps-c-and-full-frame-sensors-matter-and-why)

I would also encourage you to explore the wedding tag:

- [How do I prepare best for my first wedding photography event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29723/how-do-i-prepare-best-for-my-first-wedding-photography-event)
- [Tips for photographing a wedding](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4922/tips-for-photographing-a-wedding)
- [Can great photographs be taken with not-so-good equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36065/can-great-photographs-be-taken-with-not-so-good-equipment)